# APIM routing to non-mirrored endpoints

Tags: azure-api-management

I am adding Azure API Management to our service layer, and cannot find documentation on how to point a public API to a backend API that has a different route.

For example:
public: https://www.myapim.com/products?
should point to 
backend: https://www.mycustomdomain.com/api/products/search?

I can get the domains mapped correctly, but the route is what I struggle with.  Would I have to do this through custom policies or is there something in the Azure portal that will allow me to define this URL mapping?

I appreciate the help!

Answer (score 1):

It winds up that I needed to discover this help page which documents the set-backend-service policy.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/api-management/api-management-transformation-policies#SetBackendService

Comment: Also look into rewrite-uri policy